# How can the date be formatted using Spanish month names and day names in MAUI

Tags: maui

When I used to develop using .NET Framework, I just set the CurrentUICulture at the beginning of the application (Winforms or Web) to a culture such as "es-CL". With that, all date formatting accross the whole application changes to "es-CL" (month and day names in Spanish, decimal separator as the "," and thousand separator as the "."). That was extraordinary.

How can I achieve the same in MAUI? I don't care about creating a multi language application, so, is there an easy way to do this? I don't want to create a resx file for just one language.

Thanks
Jaime

Comment: it should default to the users system language settings

Comment: To override default on current device, `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = ...`   Somewhere in app startup code.

Comment: You can [create satellite assemblies for maui](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/create-satellite-assemblies#satellite-assembly-name-and-location) and refer to this link for more information.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve thanks. It worked when I use `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("es-CL");` in MauiProgram.cs file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ToolmakerSteve thanks. It worked when I use

`CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("es-CL");`

in MauiProgram.cs file.